# starting docker cotainer from cron not working

Tags: python, docker, cron

I'm having a problem starting my scheduled containers (i'm scheduling these starts using cron.
the call i'm doing in cron is
30 8 * * * docker run -d --rm [name of image]

I have four images all written the same, for some reason one i guess is working but still not sure.
I could do it normally but accidentally deleted my old cron file. So I only suppose I'm doing something wrong.

Can someone help me?
The images contain just some scraper scripts that I want to start everyday at 8:30 am, so i guess doing this simple is best, that's why i'm trying to do it with cron.

Comment: I think you need to use absolute path to binary (docker in your case) in a cron definition.

Comment: @zigarn as `docker` is in the `PATH`, using absolute path does not make any difference, but that's good. THE OP: what if you run `docker run -d --rm [name of image]` in your host? Does this work? When you run `docker ps -al`, can you see that?

Comment: @Saeed `cron` runs with [`$PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` by default](https://linuxize.com/post/scheduling-cron-jobs-with-crontab/).

Comment: And did it solve your issue?

Comment: @Saeed If I give docker run -d--rm directly on my command line it seems to start any normally. More strange is that one seems to be starting everyday for some reason.

Comment: @GaSab I did not what's the issue now? I've added `* * * * * cron run -d --rm ubuntu sh -c "apt update && apt install wget -y && wget SOMEFILES"` in my host and it's working fine as the moment I'm writing this comment.